# Razor Escaping my html even if I use Html.Raw

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I'm having a problem where my dynamically generated html is getting escaped and outputed on the screen. heres what I have:

```
 @{
      string TrialMessage = string.Empty;
      if ((bool)ViewBag.msd.IsOnTrial == true)
      {
           var expDate = (DateTime)ViewBag.msd.RenewalDate;
           var daysToTrialExpiation = expDate.AddDays(1) - System.DateTime.UtcNow;

           TrialMessage = "<b>Trial Ends in: <span style=\"color:[Color];\">" + (daysToTrialExpiation.Days) + "</span> Days</b>";
           if (daysToTrialExpiation.Days > 5)
           {
                TrialMessage = TrialMessage.Replace("[Color]", "green");
           }
           else if (daysToTrialExpiation.Days > 2)
           {
                TrialMessage = TrialMessage.Replace("[Color]", "orange");
           }
           else if (daysToTrialExpiation.Days > 0)
           {
                TrialMessage = TrialMessage.Replace("[Color]", "red");
           }
           else
           {
                TrialMessage = "<b style=\"color: red;\"> Trial Ended " + Math.Abs(daysToTrialExpiation.Days) + " Days Ago</b>";
           }
      } 
 }
```

When I use the TrialMessage in the View, I'm getting the escaped version of it outputted on the screen:

```
<b>Trial Ends in: <span style="color:green;">15</span> Days</b>
```

I have tried to use `Html.Raw(TrialMessage)` I've even tried to manually create an `HTMLString` with the same result. What am I missing?

**Update:** The way I'm outputting it on the view is:

```
@Html.Raw(TrialMessage)
```

Comment: Just a quick note; I would highly recommend not performing logic like this in the view. I'd recommend building a ViewModel class for this view that calculates the expiration for you so you can send the correct values to the view without this logic living in the view. That'll also result in the expiration calculation being reusable in other places without needing to repeat it (if you follow good OOP principles). You may also want to look int making some customer HtmlHelpers to help generate your custom html... once again to avoid doing processing in the view as much as possible.

Comment: post the entire line of code where you are doing Html.Raw()

Comment: @quakkels, Thanks for the suggesstions, it was very late last night and I needed to get this out asap (didn't happen though) Yeah, I'll definitely be sure to do that. With that said, This problem is still bugging me cause I can't find anything wrong with it and its not working lol

Comment: @iamkrillin, Just updated the question

Comment: @hjavaher `Html.Raw` should work.maybe you are making a mistake elsewhere.post your full code

Comment: @Selman22, Thats the full code that pertains to this section. The only thing that I'm getting from the database is the date. Everything is calculated just fine and I'm putting the `Html.Raw` on the next line inside a `<span>`

Comment: what is the html.raw in?  I don't remember which but believe you need to put that in a span or div for it to render.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In an effort to just get it working (it seems you're pressed for time) what if you removed html from the variable?

Perhaps something like this could work for you:

```
@{
  string trialColor = string.Empty;
  int trialDays = 0;
  if ((bool)ViewBag.msd.IsOnTrial)
  {
    var expDate = (DateTime)ViewBag.msd.RenewalDate;
    var trialDays = (expDate.AddDays(1) - System.DateTime.UtcNow).Days;

    if (trialDays > 5)
    {
      trialColor = "green";
    }
    else if (trialDays > 2)
    {
      trialColor = "orange";
    }
    else
    {
      trialColor = "red";
    }
  } 
}
```

...

```
@if((bool)ViewBag.msd.IsOnTrial && trialDays > 0)
{
  <strong>Trial Ends in: <span style="color:@trialColor;">@trialDays </span> Days</strong>
} else if((bool)ViewBag.msd.IsOnTrial) {
  <strong style="color: red;">Trial Ended @Math.Abs(trialDays) Days Ago</strong>
}
```

Note: untested code. It's been a bit since I've written razor.

Comment: This is the better way to accomplish this goal. The "ultimate" method would be to have this business logic in the service that is returning the view model.

Comment: @Tommy - You're right. Ideally the display code above would need very little change and the logic above would be in a class/viewModel/someothertestablesolution.

Comment: Hi quakkels, That's exactly what I ended up doing (again because of time) I can't really use a viewModel because this information is actually coming from a controller level action filter that is needed in every view and controller. With that said, its still bugging me as to why the above code didn't work lol Is this a bug in the html.raw helper or razor?

Comment: It's difficult to say whether this is a bug or not. I haven't been able to to duplicate the issue.